# Custom Delegate Methods not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, delegates, logic

Look at the following code.

In `CusFormViewController.h`

```
@interface CusFormViewController : CusBaseViewController

@protocol CusFormViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)ticketCreated:(NSString*)ticketID;
-(void)ticketFormRenderingFinished;
@end

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<CusFormViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

In `CusFormViewController.m`

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(ticketFormRenderingFinished)])
    [self.delegate ticketFormRenderingFinished];

if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(ticketCreated:)])
    [self.delegate ticketCreated:ticket_id];
```

In `ViewController.m`

```
#import "CusFormViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<CusFormViewControllerDelegate>

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CusFormViewController *formVC = [[CusFormViewController alloc] init];
    [formVC setDelegate:self];
}

-(void)ticketCreated:(NSString*)ticketID{
    NSLog(@"ticket created.");
}
-(void)ticketFormRenderingFinished{
    NSLog(@"ticket form rendered.");
}
```

The `ticketCreated` & `ticketFormRenderingFinished` are not being called.

Comment: In CusFormViewController.m check NSLog(@"%@", self.delegate);

Comment: CusFormViewController is embedded with storyboard or not?

Comment: Please post more code.

Comment: if CusFormViewController  related to storyboard     CusFormViewController *formVC = [[CusFormViewController alloc] init]; that code not work tell me your senario

Comment: @Sunny I am getting null, but why it is null, I have created property for it.

Comment: @Aruna it is not embedded with storyboard.

Comment: can you add in header file or in ViewController()
 CusFormViewController *formVC.
Because it was a local instance

Comment: @ShashikantMore that you have to debug

Comment: try removing nonatomic property of delegate & clean code & run

Answer (score 2):

Most common reason for delegate method not being called is dealing with incorrect objects.

1. Ensure that `CusFormViewController` object created from
   `ViewController` is the same which you are presenting on screen and
   that the delegate is being set on the same object. I truly believe
   you are creating a new `CusFormViewController` object and setting
   delegate on that.
2. In `CusFormViewController`, before calling delegate, check the
   existence of delegate as well. This is a safety check, you can also put a
   NSLog statement to double check if your delegate exists or not. You
   are failing here.
3. If you are segueing from `ViewController` to `CusFormViewController` then you set delegate in `prepareForSegue:` and not in `viewDidLoad`.

As a side note, put a `NSLog` statement in `viewDidLoad` of your `CusFormViewController` and print `self.delegate` to check the property setting.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller `formVC` is dealloced after the function `viewDidLoad` executed. Create strong reference on your formVC for example like this:

```
@interface ViewController ()<CusFormViewControllerDelegate>
{
    CusFormViewController *_formVC;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _formVC = [[CusFormViewController alloc] init];
    [formVC setDelegate:self];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help me out. Thanks for ur time.

Comment: @Shashi add please your `CusFormViewController.m` and `CusFormViewController.h` code. It should work)

Answer (score 0):

Hey try to create instance of  CusFormViewController using below method
 CusFormViewController * _formVC=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER_OF_YOUR_ CusFormViewController"];